# Sharing a Spread Sheet on SharePoint and making sure Data changes reflect in document

Tags: excel

I have a spread sheet to which i make changes weekly. There are different kinds of data in the spread sheet. I want to make different parts of data visible to different people in my team on the **SharePoint**. Also, whenever i make changes to my Original Spread sheet , the changes should be visible among the team members when they access their SharePoint.

Is there a way to do above? I hope i was clear enough to explain. Let me know if there is still any doubt?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restrict visibility of specific sections within a single workbook without a fair bit of VBA, but it's straightforward to create one workbook for each group of people on your team, and then use SharePoint to set visibility of those files. Simply select the file on SharePoint, click on permissions, stop inheriting permissions, and set the needed permissions per user or group.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aron. The problem is that I have 1 one big workbook and i need to update contents weekly ONLY in this workbook. And i want to make these changes visible to different people. Different people can see the changes only for some specific sections of the workbook. I was thinking of using Web Parts. Would it help? If not, any other solutions for the problem i mentioned above?

Comment: No, SharePoint does permissions on a per-file basis. You'll have to hunt down an Excel guru to tell you how to restrict permissions on a per-sheet basis. Of course, your best solution would be to get your reporting off Excel (that's not what Excel was made for) and into SharePoint lists and libraries. Then you could do all sorts of things for permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually reasonably easy but requires a bit of work to set up and does not require any coding knowledge.  When you publish the workbook, just restrict the permissions to let only you see it.  Then create a new page and start adding web parts that are business data > excel web access.  Then add the named pieces of the workbook to the different web parts.  Then go to the bottom of the web part configuration options and expand the advanced section.  Then add in the groups of people you want to be able to view each piece of the excel spread sheet and those web parts will only be visible to them.